# MediaRecorder failed when i stop the recording

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I have this error. Can somebody please help me, I think it's something about touch listener... The error is happening when I release my finger.

```
04-25 20:07:00.263: D/FB Sessions(18429): false
04-25 20:07:04.533: I/MediaRecorderJNI(18429): prepare: surface=0x189250 (identity=1813)
04-25 20:07:10.493: E/MediaRecorder(18429): stop failed: -1007
04-25 20:07:10.493: D/AndroidRuntime(18429): Shutting down VM
04-25 20:07:10.493: W/dalvikvm(18429): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018608)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429): java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at com.crewbase.rec.RecordActivity.stopRecording(RecordActivity.java:151)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at com.crewbase.rec.RecordActivity.access$2(RecordActivity.java:150)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at com.crewbase.rec.RecordActivity$1.onTouch(RecordActivity.java:79)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3897)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1153)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1721)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2200)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1884)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-25 20:07:10.503: E/AndroidRuntime(18429):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And that is happening when I try to run this code:

from touch listener:

```
/// Preview is SurfaceView in my view
preview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                prepareRecording();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //Log.d(TAG, String.format("ACTION_MOVE | x:%s y:%s", 
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                stopRecording();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And these two methods:

```
private void prepareRecording() {
    try {
        camera.unlock();

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setCamera(camera);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/rec/temp/video_" + String.valueOf(videoCount) + ".mp4");

        recorder.setOutputFile(tempFile.getPath());
        recorder.setVideoFrameRate(25);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());

        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }  catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("REDORDING :: ",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("REDORDING :: ",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    recorder.stop();
    camera.lock();
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#stop%28%29):

> Note that a `RuntimeException` is intentionally thrown to the
>   application, if no valid audio/video data has been received when
>   `stop()` is called. This happens if `stop()` is called immediately after
>   `start()`. The failure lets the application take action accordingly to
>   clean up the output file (delete the output file, for instance), since
>   the output file is not properly constructed when this happens.

In other words: Dalvik throws the exception on purpose. You have to handle it to clean up after your app. You'd have to handle it like this:

```
private void stopRecording() {
    try {
        recorder.stop();
    } catch(RuntimeException stopException) {
        // handle cleanup here
    }
    camera.lock();
}
```

Comment: is there any other way to doing this?

Comment: in my case it's not immediate start/stop, or mediaprojection with mediarecorder just doesn't work  ??
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/34986043/4548520 I can't understand why this issue happens when I stop screen recording

Comment: Thank you for this. Android should give listeners like onRecordStarted onRecordStopped. More reasons to hate Android.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar error -1007 when I was recording audio with `AMR_WB`, but it turned out that the problem was that I forgot to set sampling rate.

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case i was using Surface as the VideoSource and i just forget to set Input Surface. and then i got this -1007 error.

And i fixed by giving Input Surface and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem of **stop failed** while stopping the video after click on my stopScreenCapturing() method but only for the second time, first time it was just working fine.
My this code fixed it for me finally. Hope it will help someone here.

To stop screen capturing write

```
     private fun stopScreenCapturing() {
            
            if (mMediaRecorder == null) {
                return
            }
            mMediaRecorder?.stop()
            mMediaRecorder?.reset()

//mVirtualDisplay is used to mirror the projection and bind it to mediarecorder's surfaceview
            if(mVirtualDisplay==null)
            {
                return
            }
            mVirtualDisplay.release()

//MediaProjection API
            if (projection != null) {
                projection?.unregisterCallback(cbk)
                projection?.stop()
                projection = null
            }

//a flag is maintained to check if recording is started or not
                videoRecordingStarted = false
        }
```

and next time when you want to record again then call these lines in same sequence:

```
  private fun initRecorder() {

            mMediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
            mMediaRecorder!!.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
            mMediaRecorder!!.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
            mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
            mMediaRecorder!!.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
            mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000)
            mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoFrameRate(30)
            mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoSize(
                mContext.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels,
                mContext.resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
            )
        mMediaRecorder!!.setOutputFile(getFilePath())
           try {
            mMediaRecorder!!.prepare()
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
```

and after that start your recording. Always call prepare() before start() method as i did.

```
      private fun startVideoCapture() {
    
//i need to use this resultdata multiple times after getting permission, so i stored it in global variable
            if (projection == null) {
                projection = mediaprojectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, resultData!!)
              
            }
    
                mVirtualDisplay = projection?.createVirtualDisplay(
                    "ScreenCapture",
                    480, 640,
                    resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi,
                    VIRT_DISPLAY_FLAGS, mMediaRecorder?.surface, null, null
                )!!
    
            mMediaRecorder?.start()
    
            videoRecordingStarted = true
        }
```

So, Basically why i was getting this error?

> Because i was not setting up my virtual display(mVirutalDisplay) again
> after releasing it and making my projection null. If you are not using then you can bind your own surfaceview.